# Parse string using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to search about some characters (or word) in text using `JavaScript`  and remove the line that starts this characters/word..

### example

remove the lines that start with ( He ) ..

### input

```
Hello world, 
He like cats and dogs
Bye bye
```

### output

```
Hello world, 
Bye bye
```

Comment: I found the string. but how to remove the line that starts with this word

Comment: In which format you have initial string, how to judge line delimeter ?

Comment: @adham, show us what code you've tried so far then!

Comment: I have text with multiple lines, no delimiters just lines below each other

Comment: @adham - The line *is* the delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the pos of the "He " using the indexOf method and then get the position of the next line-break to remove that line using the substring method.

```
var someString = "Hello world,\n" +
    "He like cats and dogs\n" +
    "Bye bye";

var pos = someString.indexOf('He ');
var nextLineBreak = someString.indexOf('\n', pos);

var firstPart = someString.substring(0, pos);
var secondPart = someString.substring(nextLineBreak +1);

var finalString = firstPart + secondPart;
alert(finalString);
```

jsFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/zw2Gh/

Comment: +1 but it only takes care of one occurence.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string up into separate lines, throw away the lines you want, and finally join the lines back into one string:

```
var string = "test\nHe test\ntest"; // "\n" represents a newline

var result = string.split("\n") // split into lines
                   .filter(function(line) {              // only retain lines
                       return line.indexOf("He ") !== 0; // that don't start
                   })                                    // with "He " *
                   .join("\n"); // join the lines back into one string
```

*) "Doesn't start" means: the characters are not apperant at index `0` in the line.

Comment: Minor note: it should be `"He "` not `"He"`

Comment: @lwburk: I just noticed that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a single line regex based replace:

```
someString.replace(/^He .*(\n|$)/mg, '');
```

It enables the multiline and global flags (mg) which allows us to use ^ and $ to match after and before newlines. And it also will remove all occurrences of the pattern. If you want lines with just `"He\n"` to be replaced, you will need to make the `' .*'` optional, like so:

```
someString.replace(/^He( .*)?(\n|$)/mg, '');
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Best solution here.